# ros publisher not publishing in debug

Tags: ros, c++, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm running my node in debug (vscode) and getting weird results.
I have a loop which is publishing to a motor

```
while (std::abs(orientation.roll) > ROLL_FLAT_SURFACE)
{     
    ros::spinOnce();
    bla bla bla


    robotControlPublisher_.publish(motor_cmd_);
    ros::Duration(TIME_TO_SLEEP).sleep();
    
    
}
```

if I put a breakpoint before and after the loop and run in debug the publisher will publish.
if I stop each iteration the publisher won't publish.
how can I fix it?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393242/ros-publisher-not-publishing-in-debug/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2021-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-12-22**:
What do you mean by "stop each iteration"?

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2021-12-23**:
put a breakpoint after ros::spinOnce(); press F5 to run to the next breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The debugger is probably stopping the entire ROS infrastructure in your process before it's had a chance to actually publish your message. `ros::spinOnce()` only spins the processing loop once, and when that returns and the debugger stops your process, the message might not have made it through the entire publishing process yet.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2021-12-24**:
This command (ros::Duration(TIME_TO_SLEEP).sleep should have helped

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2021-12-24**:
TIME_TO_SLEEP =0.1